# How to get variables to appear in PHP Storm Live Templates?

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I created a live template in PHP Storm:

[image]

I understand that the cursor is supposed to surround the name `$objects$` so I can type it in and then go onto the next variable.

**However**, when I type `forrr` and press `TAB`, I get this:

[image]

**What do I have to change so that when I press `TAB` that the cursor is waiting for me on the name of the first variable?**

*ADDENDUM*

Here is my full context screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. Please show whole template details (including Context and Edit Variables screen). Here is mine: http://postimg.org/image/klo7h26u9/

Comment: Ok, I added the screenshot above. Do the variable names display when you type `forrr` and `TAB` in your editor? That used to work but somewhere while experimenting they stopped appearing. How do I get them back?

Comment: No -- they are not. And they should NOT.

Comment: Updated my answer to hopefully cover more bases

Comment: If that isn't what you're looking for, can you post a screenshot mockup of what your desired result is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up this Live Template, go to the "Edit variables" dialog, and set the order of the variables. The listed order in that dialog is the order in which it prompts you for input.

### Other notes (edits)

#### 1. Pre-filled variable names:

If you set the default value of the `$objects$` variable to `"$objects"`, you'll get that value pre-filled:
[image: default]
[image: in-line]

You will only need to edit once, and pressing tab will take you to the `$object` spot. I'd also suggest that you add the `$END$` variable between the brackets of the `foreach()` so when you finish editing, you're brought inside the code block.

#### 2. Hardcoded variable names

If you change the Live Template for hard-coded PHP variables, just remove the trailing `$` from the variable name. This will directly paste your hard-coded variables.

[image: hard-coded]
[image: hard-coded results]

Comment: I switched the variables around, now the cursor lands where the first variable is, but the variable names are displaying, how do I get them to display?

Comment: You have to type them in. If you want a default value, you'll need to populate that in the Edit Variables dialog under "Default Value".

If you want the `$objects$` variable to be pre-filled with your selection, you'll have to use the `$SELECTION$` variable, and access the Live Template from "Surround With" (Ctrl-Alt-T, by default)

Comment: If you literally want "`$objects`" to show up in the live template, then you should remove the trailing $ so it becomes a direct text fill-in, instead of a PhpStorm live template variable